# How to run Python with ACE Editor

Tags: javascript, python, cdn, cloudflare, ace-editor

I'm trying to create an online python editor and want to use Ace Editor to do so. How does one render or compile python code on the browser using Ace Editor's CDN with HTML/JS (https://ace.c9.io)?

I was successful in compiling a live view of HTML and Javascript using the `contentWindow.document` function; however, I can't seem to figure out how to do the same, except with Python instead.

Answer (score 1):

**ACE Editor is just a code editor, it doesn't include any compiler of any kind.** What you are looking for is for a web service that allows you to submit some Python code, then run it on the host server with Python support and return a response.

The best solution would be to implement a Python Sandbox that will run untrusted Python code, ideally through docker or something on a virtual machine where no other code or data of yours could be compromised. Check [Pysandbox for a docker solution example](https://github.com/StepicOrg/epicbox).